# Visual composer seperator line between columns

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i'm using the visual composer plugin which makes it easy to create columns. i've reached a issue where i want to create a sepa

```css
html,body { height:100%;width:auto;}

.left {
float: left;

}
#w1 {width:22%;
background-color:#009;
    margin-right: 4%;
    
}
#w2{width:48%;
background-color:#9F3;
    margin-right: 4%;
}
#w3{ width:22%;
background-color:#30C;}
```

```html
<div class="left" id="w1">TEST</div>
<div class="left" id="w2">TEST</div>
<div class="left" id="w3">TEST</div>
```

rator line between the columns how can this be done in an easy way? I've recreated how the 3 columns are set up below:

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:after` :pseudo-elements.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#w1 {
  width: 22%;
  background-color: #009;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
#w2 {
  width: 48%;
  background-color: #9F3;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
#w3 {
  width: 22%;
  background-color: #30C;
}
.left:not(:nth-of-type(2)):after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -10%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background: black;
}
.left:last-of-type:after {
  right: 108%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left" id="w1">TEST</div>
<div class="left" id="w2">TEST</div>
<div class="left" id="w3">TEST</div>
```

Comment: @PeterPik - "_add one to the right aswell?_" - Where exactly?

Comment: on both side of the green column

Comment: @PeterPik - Do you mean four seperators in total?